# can't update to mercurial branch with sub-repository

Tags: mercurial

```
hg update develop --clean
remote: conq: repository does not exist.
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

I would like to be able to switch to my develop branch, to undo my last 2 commits and merge the develop branch with tip or close it!

OR

just close and rename the branch, but since I can not update to it I don't know what to do.
I would like to: overwrite branch x with branch y:

```
hg update x
hg commit --close-branch -m 'closing branch x, will be overwriten with branch y'
hg update y
hg branch -f x
hg ci
```

but i can't update to x. How to fix/force this?

Answer (score 0):

I used the MQ extension:

```
hg qinit
hg qimport -r 4:tip
hg qpop -a
hg qdelete 4.diff
hg qpush -a
hg qfinish -a
```

That worked but after a pull the removed stuff was back in..

But, I just created a new Branch one from tip using -f with the same name.
that works good enough for me. Can't remove the 'wrong' branch it since it is 'out of the bottle' published.